# How can I specify the position for a new column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

If I have a table with the columns:

```
id | name | created_date
```

and would like to add a column, I use:

```
alter table my_table add column email varchar(255)
```

Then the column is added after the `created_date` column.

Is there any way I can specify the position for the new column? e.g. so I can add it after `name` and get a table like:

```
id | name | email | created_date
```

Comment: There is no need to do that. Just put them into your select statement in the order you want them.

Comment: @jonas so you could also create a `view` that show's it in that order... technically the position of the column shouldn't matter as you can define them in any order in a query... and you generally shouldn't be doing a `select *`

Comment: @a_horse: Well, it's much harder to work (as a developer/admin) with the tables when the columns has many different orders. When I have 15 columns in a table I really prefer to have them in the same order in all databases.

Comment: @xeno: ah, a view would be a solution, but it's just another thing to keep updated :( The column order keeps me away from doing errors (miss columns) when I do software development.

Comment: @jonas you can define column names when doing inserts and updates and thus make the order irrelevant.

Comment: @xeno: Yes. But the problem is when I list the columns using `\d mytable` in `psql` and check with my fields in my source code e.g. both in Java and JavaScript.

Comment: @xeno: Another example is that I often have a column `created` of type Timestamp. This is a kind of meta-column, and it helps if that is the last column in every table, even after adding columns to the table.

Comment: @Jonas: Then write your own alternative to \d that reports the columns in the order you want (it is only a query on the system tables: try using the `psql -E` switch to see the actual query)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name While it has no meaning in the SQL, where the tables and the query results are sets of records, it still might have a high importance on a software design sense. Furthermore, typically the order of the columns on the deep-level also exists and it might have an importance. To me, this rigidity is a serious disadvantage of the postgresql.

Comment: @peterh: well, the only main stream DBMS that supports this is MySQL/MariaDB and I will always trade the many advantages of Postgres over the possibility to change the position of a column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I fully agree with that, I do the same. It is not a big problem that making such a reorder requires multiple DDL queries, in exchange what... troubles can we have with other SQL engines which practically never happen with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` will only add the new column at the end, as the last one.
In order to create a new column in another position you need to recreate the table and copy the data from the old/current table in this new table.

Comment: "[or by adding columns and rotating data until you reach the desired layout](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position)"

Comment: That's right.. but does anyone really use this method? :-)

Comment: If it is easier than recreating the table and all [children tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-inherit.html), foreign keys and grants :) I thought the link might be useful either way as it offers an explanation of why you can't specify position and hope that it might be implemented in a future version.

Comment: @JackDouglas and 8 years later I'm in a position where I might be forced to use this exact method! Love you, man!

Comment: I guess I have mixed feelings about this still being useful! It looks like the latest effort to make progress on this was [in 2015](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/1185313031.785041.1424990529572.JavaMail.yahoo%40mail.yahoo.com#dc57f5bb07c31250880481aeeeff1229) in case you are interested.

Comment: @JackDouglas - It would still think it's useful.  I found this thread just now as I'm prototyping a couple new tables, and would like the columns to appear the way I'm thinking about them ("Oh - I see I'll need an extra column 'here'").  And in quick prototyping, I don't want to do a long select query or specify the column order in an INSERT.  Also, a natural or intuitive column order from a simple `\d` can go a long way towards "self documentation" for someone else trying to pick up the database - maybe even a later You!  :-)

Comment: In INFORMIX you add "BEFORE <column_name>" at the end of the ALTER TABLE statement.

Answer (score 36):

You'll need to recreate the table if you want a certain order.  Just do something like:

```
alter table tablename rename to oldtable;
create table tablename (column defs go here);
insert into tablename (col1, col2, col3) select col2, col1, col3 from oldtable;
```

Create indexes as needed etc.

Answer (score 9):

If you want this just for looks, I find it easier to keep a view per each table with desired order of columns, and select from it instead of the table.

```
create table my_table (
create view view_my_table as
  select id, name, created_date from my_table;

-- adding a new column
begin;
alter table my_table add column email varchar(255);
drop view view_my_table;
create view view_my_table as
  select id, name, email, created_date from my_table;
commit;
```

For all other purposes (like insert, union) it is better to always specify the column list.

```
-- bad
insert into my_table values (...);
(select * from my_table)
  union all
(select * from my_table);

-- good
insert into my_table (id, name, email, created_date) values (...);
(select id, name, email, created_date from my_table)
  union all
(select id, name, email, created_date from my_table);
```